# EF Data setting ViewModel

Tags: c#

I have a ViewModel where objects are all `string` and the model from the database `Address` is a list. I wanted to know if there is any other way to set the viewModel string values other then the way I have it done below? Any advice on how I can combine the two ListOfProducts.Select lines?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //EF Data
            List<Address> ListOfProducts = new List<Address>();
            ListOfProducts.Add(new Address() { StreetLine1="address 1",StreetLine2="address line2 1" });
            ViewModelAddress vm = new ViewModelAddress();
            vm.StreetLine1 = ListOfProducts.Select(a => a.StreetLine1).FirstOrDefault();
            vm.StreetLine2 = ListOfProducts.Select(a => a.StreetLine2).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        class Address
        {
            public string StreetLine1 { get; set; }
            public string StreetLine2{ get; set; }
        }
        class ViewModelAddress
        {
            public string StreetLine1 { get; set; }
            public string StreetLine2 { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. It is unclear what you are asking. What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: I wanted to know if there a way I can combined the two `ListOfProducts.Select` lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var vm = ListOfProducts.Select(a => new ViewModelAddress
                {StreetLine1 = a.StreetLine1, StreetLine2 = a.StreetLine2}).FirstOrDefault();
```